# Aurelia: translate + parameter comes from value converter

Tags: aurelia

I use an value converter to format date format:

```
${date | formatDate}
```

Next I'd like to use this formatted date as a translator parameter. Something like this way:

```
${'dateOfCreation' | t: {'date': ${date | formatDate}}}
```

But it doesn't work. Is it even possible to do that in Aurelia? If not, how should I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Aurelia currently does not support nested value converters. You can use this as a workaround:

```
<div ref="myDiv" formatted-date="${date | formatDate}">
  ${'dateOfCreation' | t: { 'date': myDiv.formattedDate } }
</div>
```

Hope this helps!